# htaccess to block specific file in a folder

Tags: .htaccess

i am sorry if this question has been ask before.
I have a folder that look like: project/version/download.zip
but the thing is i have multiple project folder and with multiple version folder
where I have a few files that i do not want anyone to access to in version folder but i want to allow user to access to download.zip

my question is how do i block access to other files but allow user to download the zip?
as for the file is just a File type.

or should i just transfer the zip file to some other folders and put deny from all in the project folder?

Please advice ^^ thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your folder where your zip file resides, try adding `.htaccess` file with following in it:

```
Order Allow,Deny 
Deny from all 
<FilesMatch "\.zip$">
Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have .htaccess files in your version folders yet. If you have mod_rewrite enabled you should be able to do something like this:

First add a .htaccess file to the version folder. Add the following to that file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(download\.zip|grumpycat\.png)$
RewriteRule ^ [F,L]
```

Since the .htaccess file is in the version folder, all filenames are automatically prefixed with `version/`. It will block access to all files in that folder, and subfolders without .htaccess, except for download.zip and grumpycat.png. You can simpy copy and paste this file in any subfolder you want to restrict access to.

---

Alternativelly, if you alter the code slightly, you can instead make a .htaccess in your document root. You would do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(version|version1337|version9001)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(download\.zip|grumpycat\.png)$
RewriteRule ^ [F,L]
```

Now the requested url must begin with version, version1337 or version9001 and must not end with one of those filenames to trigger the forbidden error. Otherwise the file will be shown.